# IBM DataStage - unstructured data stage imports NULL from excel cells that contain formulas

Tags: excel, import, null, stage, datastage

I'm loading an excel file into a dataset using DataStage 11.7.1.1. The excel file has some columns which contain formulas: column L=D4+E4+F4. All the cells that contain formulas are imported as NULL in the dataset. The import option is set as value. Whatever I choose (formula, etc), the result is still NULL.

Am I missing something? Is this some kind of bug?

Thank you!

If I remove the formulas from the file and use values in the cells, the import is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have version 11.7.1.1? In IIS v11.7.1.4, this is a known issue. You can read about it here:

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/defect/aCI3p000000LAQ9/dt161026?language=en_US

Copied from the patch's readme file:

PATCH NAME             : patch_DT161026_cc_unstructured_all_11714

APAR SUMMARY           : When reading an excel file, cell reference value in a sheet gives NULL

PROBLEM DETAILS        : When reading an excel file, cell reference value in a sheet gives NULL. The issue occurs on 11.7.1.4

RESOLUTION             : Unstructured Stage job reading an Excel file returns NULL whose Cell content is a reference from another Cell. The reference Cell can be in same or a different sheet. It is able to print only Cell values whose content is NOT a reference from another Cell but entered manually. This is a regression due to migration of Unstructured Stage to Apache POI version 5.2.2 on 11.7.1.4.

Kind Regards,
Emily